# draw a sine wave using c?

Tags: c, bgi

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <dos.h>


int main() {

    int gd = DETECT, gm;

    int angle = 0;

    double x, y;

    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");


    line(0, getmaxy() / 2, getmaxx(), getmaxy() / 2);

    /* generate a sine wave */

    for(x = 0; x < getmaxx(); x+=3) {

        /* calculate y value given x */

        y = 50*sin(angle*3.141/180);

        y = getmaxy()/2 - y;

        /* color a pixel at the given position */

        putpixel(x, y, 15);

        delay(100);

        /* increment angle */

        angle+=5;

    }

    getch();

    /* deallocate memory allocated for graphics screen */

    closegraph();

    return 0;

}
```

This is the program. Why are we incrementing the angle and how this angle is relevant to graph? I changed the value of angle to 0 and the wave became a straight line. I want to know what is happening with this increment.

Comment: What are your thoughts about possible answers to your questions or solutions to your problems?

Comment: the curves are generated if the angle is incremented else not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are we incrementing the angle and how this angle is relevant to graph

The [sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine) takes an angle as argument, typically in radiant. The program implements the angle in degrees, so it's getting scaled to radiant the moment is gets passed to `sin()`.

The sine function is periodical to (repeats itself after) 2*pi or 360 degrees:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
|       angle       | sin(angle) |
+---------+---------+            |
| Radiant | Degrees |            |
+---------+---------+------------+
|       0 |       0 |          0 |
+---------+---------+------------+
|  1/2*pi |      90 |          1 |
+---------+---------+------------+
|      pi |     180 |          0 |
+---------+---------+------------+
|  3/2*pi |     270 |         -1 | 
+---------+---------+------------+
|    2*pi |     360 |          0 |
+---------+---------+------------+
|  5/2*pi |     450 |          1 |
+---------+---------+------------+
|    3*pi |     540 |          0 |
+---------+---------+------------+
|  7/2*pi |     630 |         -1 | 
+---------+---------+------------+
|    4*pi |     720 |          0 |
+---------+---------+------------+
|     ... |     ... |        ... |

and so on ...
```

> changed the value of angle to 0 and the wave became a straight line

The result of `sin(0)` is `0`.

[For the mathematical derivation you might like to have a look here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/trig-functions/graphs-of-sine-cosine-tangent-alg2/v/we-graph-domain-and-range-of-sine-function).

Comment: why we need to increment the angle every time?

Comment: @SudhirSharma  if you look at this [graph of a sine wave](http://www.bbc.co.uk/staticarchive/e7e67ed6a11c84d63b6c56122fa1702908882e54.gif), you will see the x-axis is marked in degrees. In your program every 3 pixels on the screen (the step in `x`) corresponds to 5 degrees (the step in `angle`).

Comment: @WeatherVane so this means every pixel on the screen is generated at a angle difference of 5 degrees.